# How to mute a video on iOS while iPod still playing audio?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, video

I'm developing a teaching app playing video animations with no sound.
I would like to prevent the movie player from stopping other audio sessions (such as the iPod) when the video is launched.

Is there any way to indicate the iOS the video has no audio or play in mute mode?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can always detect if the music is playing and and resume it right way after the movie started playing.

Detecting player state
`[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState]`

Resume
`[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe something like this

```
UInt32 allowMixing = YES;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
```

should do the the trick.

Keep in mind, you'll need to add the `AudioToolbox` library to your application, and add:

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

to your classes imports in order to use the above code.

It should allow your app's sounds to mix with the other app's sounds in the background. In this case, since your app is silent, it will just allow background sounds to keep playing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I should note that you need to look at the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers) as there are times you'll need to set this property again (during phone calls, for instance).

Comment: I tried to add a little more info to make it easier on you. Hope it helps!